# Convert multiple "Object" formats to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, string, date

There "Financial_Year" column has multiple formats of object. I would like to standardise them into "YYYY" format like below:

| Financial_Year | "NEW"_Year |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-21 | 2020 |
| 2019-20 | 2019 |
| 2013 | 2013 |
| 2009 | 2009 |

I tried to use the below code that I found here but it seems does not work in my case:

```
df['format'] = 1
df.loc[df['Financial_Year'].str.contains('YYYY'), 'format'] = 2
df['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Financial_Year'])

df.loc[df.format == 1, 'Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[df.format ==1, '%Y-%y'], format = 'YYYY-YY').dt.strftime('%Y-%y')
df.loc[df.format == 2, 'Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[df.format ==2, '%Y'], format = 'YYYY').dt.strftime('%Y')
```

This is the error I got "ValueError: Given date string not likely a datetime."

I do some other internet search but I cannot figure out the solution yet.

Thank you in advance and appreciate for your helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to get four digits appearing in a row:

```
df['New_Year'] = df['Financial_Year'].str.extract('(\d{4})')
```

Output:

```
   Financial_Year   New_Year
0         2020-21       2020
1         2019-20       2019
2            2013       2013
3            2009       2009
```

Answer (score 1):

I think solution should be simplify by spliting by `-` and selecting first `year`:

```
df['Year'] = df['Financial_Year'].str.split('-').str[0]
```

If need working with datetimes and match only formats `YYYY-YY` and `YYYY` use:

```
d1 = pd.to_datetime(df['Financial_Year'], format = '%Y-%y', errors='coerce')
d2 = pd.to_datetime(df['Financial_Year'], format = '%Y', errors='coerce')

df['Year'] =  d1.fillna(d2).dt.year
```